# Getting Quandl Data via Pandas Data-Reader

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I am having trouble using pandas-datareader to import data from Quandl.  Here is the code that I have tried (with a real API key):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
from datetime import date

start=date(1970,1,1)
end=date.today()
ticker='F'
qkey=[My API Key]

pdr.QUANDL_API_KEY=qkey
QUANDL_API_KEY=qkey
pdrquandl=pdr.DataReader('WIKI/'+ticker,'quandl',start,end)      
pdrquandl=pdr.DataReader('WIKI/'+ticker,'quandl',start,end,api_key=qkey)
```

I get the following error messages when I run this:

```
>>> pdrquandl=pdr.DataReader('WIKI/'+ticker,'quandl',start,end)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 379, in DataReader
    session=session, api_key=access_key).read()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\quandl.py", line 54, in __init__
    raise ValueError('The Quandl API key must be provided either '
ValueError: The Quandl API key must be provided either through the api_key variable or through the environmental variable QUANDL_API_KEY.
>>> pdrquandl=pdr.DataReader('WIKI/'+ticker,'quandl',start,end,api_key=qkey)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: DataReader() got an unexpected keyword argument 'api_key'
```

What am I missing?  How do I provide the API key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/data.py) shows how the DataReader factory function passes it to the Quandl reader:

```
elif data_source == "quandl":
        return QuandlReader(symbols=name, start=start, end=end,
                            retry_count=retry_count, pause=pause,
                            session=session, api_key=access_key).read()
```

So try passing it to DataReader with the `access_key` argument:

```
pdrquandl=pdr.DataReader('WIKI/'+ticker,'quandl',start,end,access_key=qkey)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach to quandl

```
import quandl 
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = "API-KEY"
aapl = quandl.get("WIKI/TICKER", start_date="YEAR-MONTH-DAY", end_date="YEAR-MONTH-DAY")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Configuration**

> - MAC OS
> - VS Code
> - Python 3.x

**Method**

> - Run this code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
api_key = [YOUR_API_KEY]
pdrquandl = pdr.DataReader("WIKI/TICKER", 'quandl', start_date, end_date, api_key)
```